# Yii2 переопределить exception для изменения формата ответа?

Tags: php, yii2, исключения

Подскажите, как правильно переопределить exception чтобы в итоге ответ был только с "message", на данный момент используется HttpException.

**Текущий формат ответа:**

`{ "name": "...", "message": "...", "code": 500, "status": 500, "type": "..." }`

**Какой нужен:**

`{ "message": "..." }`